# Runtime error while doing string concatenation

Tags: c, string, concatenation

What is the problem with the below program?

```
main( ) 
{ 
 char *str1 = "United" ; 
 char *str2 = "Front" ; 
 char *str3 ; 
 str3 = strcat ( str1, str2 ) ; 
 printf ( "\n%s", str3 ) ; 
}
```

I am not able to compile the above program and it always give me runtime error. I am trying to concatenate the two string. Is there any error in the above program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make your `char *str1 = "United"` as

`char str1[<required memory for concatenated resultant string>] = "United"`.

You need to allocate memory for the destination buffer which is `str1`. `str3` will also receive address of `str1` in the result. 'strcat' will not check for space availability in destination buffer (str1). Programmer has to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a string literal, but your compiler (and runtime support) won't let you.  When you do so, you are invoking 'undefined behaviour', which is a Bad Thing!™  Anything could happen; it is legitimate for the program to crash.  Avoid undefined behaviour.

You need to allocate enough (writable) memory for the strings, maybe like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = "United";
    char *str2 = "Front";
    char  str3[64];
    strcpy(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str3);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: what "a bad Thing!™" mean?

Comment: It means that your program won't behave reliably...but it doesn't mean there's actually a trademark on a 'Bad Thing!™'.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `char *str = "someText"`, basically, you initialize a pointer to a string constant which can't be changed, and is located somewhere in your computer's memory.

After that by using the function `strcat()` you are trying to change that string constant, which we said is constant - 
Such behavior compiles with no errors, but will cause your program to crash during runtime since `const` (constant) works during runtime and is not precompiled like `#define`.

A different solution for you might be,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {

    char* str1 = "Hello,";
    char* str2 = " World";
    char str3[30];

    strcpy(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3, str2);

    printf("%s\n", str3);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps!
Best of luck in the future!